# Where to securely store CA cert for SSL connection to MySQL in Heroku

Tags: php, mysql, ssl, heroku

I am working on a Heroku app written in PHP that connects securely to a MySQL db (JawsDB add-on). What's the best practice on where to store the CA cert needed to establish the secure connection?
I am currently storing it in a sub-directory of my app's main directory, but is there a better practice?
Is there maybe any heroku add-on that can store these files in such a way that they can be securely referred to from the code?

Comment: If you can provide the CA contents as a string instead of reading it from a file then you can store it in your app environment configuration

Comment: Thank you for the answe @apokryfos. I am using mysqli::ssl_set and it looks like it only accepts a path to a file. https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.ssl-set.php Is there any other method you know that takes a string?